# Xamarin Forms - How to create a compose message entry?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

How to create this kind of massive entry in xamarin forms xaml?

**Concept image**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor) control

```
<Editor HeightRequest="400" />
```

Answer (score 3):

you are looking for an editor

```
<Editor/>
```

[Editor Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.editor?view=xamarin-forms)